# Authorized call of a lambda which does not require authorization to optionally get username

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I have a lambda function get-profile. It returns a user's profile similiar to an instagram profile. It has a follow button which behaves differently depending if the viewer is signed in or not. If the vieweris signed in and already following the user, the button text instead shows unfollow.
My lambda function has no authorization since I want every visitor of the site the be able to view user profiles. The serverless.yml setups looks like this:

```
    handler: api/get-profile.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: users/{id}
          method: get
          cors: true
```

Now I want receive additional information if a signed in user calls this function, so I can find out if A is already following B. **How can I handle authorized and unauthorized cases inside the same function?** 
I am using aws-iam for authorization.
My best idea is to create another function get-profile-authorized but this way I'd have two different end points to call plus additional case handling inside my react app. Another option is creating a custom authorizer which requires me to write the complete authentication process by myself which might be very error prone. Do you guys have an idea to solve this easily?

If calling the current put-profile which does not require authentication as an signed in user, the lambda function does not receive any information about the callee.

> event.requestContext.identity

looks like this.

```
            "cognitoIdentityPoolId": null,
            "accountId": null,
            "cognitoIdentityId": null,
            "caller": null,
            "sourceIp": "93.104.81.250",
            "principalOrgId": null,
            "accessKey": null,
            "cognitoAuthenticationType": null,
            "cognitoAuthenticationProvider": null,
            "userArn": null,
            "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0",
            "user": null
        }
```

adding authorization inside **serverless.yml** would fill in that information but then I cannot be called by unauthorized users.

> authorizer: aws_iam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely want to add another lamba as you described. Otherwise you can also handle the authentication yourself, manually checking for the authorization token in the headers and authenticating it against cognito but I would advise against it.
You want to do 2 different things. You should write 2 different lambdas.